# pdo button delete row

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

when specific user login it will display what he has books.. and inside each book delete button .. i want delete row when i clicked on delete button ... but when i clicked on delete button it reload the page please i need help

this getbooks function

```
public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2)
{
    $sql_start = $start * $limit;
    $sql_limit = $limit;

    //SELECT loginUser.username, Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username="loay";
    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([
        ':username' => $this->username
        //,':start' => $start, ':limit' => $limit
    ]);
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

   echo "<table border='1'>
   <form method='POST'>
    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' method='post' >" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form";

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        die("SS");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are simply submitting the current page, thats why its reloading. If you dont want it to reload and only the data to be send to delete then go for Ajax concept

Comment: Have you try this? ` echo "<td>" ."<form method='POST'><input type='hidden' value='".$row['nameOfBook']."'><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' ' ></form>" . "</td>"; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the delete functionality using jquery and ajax.

Above your form code add:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function deleteBook(b) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var book = $(b).parent('td').prev('td').html();
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete book - "+book+"?") == false){
        return;
    }
    var ids = $(b).attr('id').substr(6).split('-');
    var book_id_to_delete = ids[0];
    var user_id = ids[1];
    //alert("book_id is " + book_id_to_delete + ", user_id is " + user_id);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "" + "deletebook.php",
      data: {
        'book_id': book_id_to_delete,
        'user_id': user_id,
        submit: 'submit',
      },
      success: function(res) {
        if (res == "deleted") {
          $(b).closest('tr').remove();
        } else {
          alert(res);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

In getBooks() function, I added id attribute (containing book and user ids) in delete button so our js code will know which books of a user should be deleted.

Replace your getBooks() function with:

```
<?php
public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2)
{
    $sql_start = $start * $limit;
    $sql_limit = $limit;

    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([
        ':username' => $this->username
    ]);
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

   echo "<table border='1'>

    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' id='delete".$row['book_id']."-".$row['user_id']."' onclick='deleteBook(this)' name='delete' value='Delete'>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "";

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        die("SS");
    }
}

?>
```

Create a class function that handles user's book deletion.

In your User class in User.php, add the following function:

```
public function deleteBook($book_id, $user_id)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM userBook WHERE book_id = :book_id AND user_id = :user_id");
    $stmt->bindValue(":book_id", $book_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(":user_id", $user_id);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

The below code will be executed by via ajax so that the chosen book will be deleted from database.

Create a file named - deletebook.php

And add this code:

```
<?php
    include_once('User.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $object = new User();
        if($object->deleteBook($_POST['book_id'], $_POST['user_id'])){
            die('deleted');
        }
        else {
            die("fail");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: He give me this error 
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in ......

Comment: I did exactly  what you say

Comment: Btw, make sure to backup of your database before you continue.

Comment: when i enter true user name and password he give this 

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/html/User.php on line 111

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/html/User.php on line 111

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170934/discussion-between-karlo-kokkak-and-husam-almasri).

Comment: and there is no button delete inside each row